# How to determine whether browser supports http2?

Tags: http2

I want to know in server side, whether or not browser supports http2 protocol.

How this can be done? Can I somehow query browser (from server / client sides)?

Answer (score 2):

Browsers that send HTTP/2 requests send the HTTP protocol version string in the request line:

```
GET / HTTP/2.0
Host: domain.com
```

Browsers that send HTTP/1.1 requests send it in this way:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: domain.com
```

Depending on what API you use on the server, you would be able to query the request's protocol version, and obtain the value for that particular request.

For example, if you are using the Servlet API on the server you can do:

```java
String protocol = httpServletRequest.getProtocol();
if (protocol.startsWith("HTTP/2")) {
    // Your logic here.
}
```

Alternatively, you can query the server for the negotiated ALPN protocol for a particular connection.

This API is not available in the Servlet API (yet), but you may be able to get this information from vendor specific APIs.

In this way you will know that *a particular request* is HTTP/2, but that is enough to tell you that the browser does supports HTTP/2.

Browsers that support HTTP/2 prefer to use HTTP/2 over HTTP/1.1, so you can typically rule out the case where the browser *could* support HTTP/2 but for some reason sends requests using HTTP/1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Some servers offer [support for that](https://www.shimmercat.com/en/info/articles/forwarded-header/#distinguishing-between-http-1-1-and-http-2-clients-protocol-).

Failing that, you can always use the user agent string and do some string mapping with version cut-outs for well known user agents. I know for example that curl supports HTTP/2 from version 7.43 onward. In general, versions of the main browsers released after summer 2015 should support HTTP/2.

Comment: for example, IE11 on Windows 7 does not supports HTTP2, while on Windows 10 it does. Can I know that from user agent?

Comment: @Illidan Good point. Sorry for not being able to help further.